# How should I add an attribute to persisted Entities?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I'm using JDO and the google datastore in my appengine java app, all working fine.

When I add a new attribute to a @PersistanceCapable Class and deploy it, the "old" already persisted Entities are not shown anymore. I do not really unterstand what's happening. Has someone theoretical background to share on this subject ? If you replace a Class with a new version of the same one (serialUID field staying the same), compile and deploy it, you should also be able to loop in the existing "old version" Entities and update them with the missing information, so that they will stay available to the application ! How to achieve this ? I have no idea.

E.G. I habe about 35 "Location" Entities (Location.class). I update Location.class to provide a new @Persistent attribute "Long LocationExternalID;" along with it's getter/setter(s). I also change my App code to use this field. How to loop in all the old Entities to add this new Attribute and set it's value?
It looks like testing if the attribute is available before deserialization ?

I cannot delete and re-create the old Entities, because of theyr Keys being referenced in unowned relationships. Too much work to do so.

Not shown means via the query, wich fetches all elements at app loading to display in a drop-down. Then when I add a new one via tha app, it appears in the drop down and behaves as expected. All elements including the old ones are visible in the datastore viewer.

Comment: define "not shown". Where ? datastore viewer? some query?

Comment: and the query is? and the log says what when performing the query ? and presumably using v2 of the GAE JDO plugin.